# Is there anyway to make work the nth-child() in ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using `nth-child()`  (both 'odd' and 'even')  in my site,

which works fine in all browsers other than ie8, without using any js or jquery.

Can we make work these pseudo classes in ie8.

(I am not supposed to use any js or Jquery)

Thanks in Advance :)

Suggestions please.

my code is something like this,

```
.row-strip{
float: left;
min-height: 1px;
padding: 0px 3px;
&:nth-child(even){
    background-color: @tableRowZebraBackgroundColor;
}
&:hover{
    background-color: @tableRowHoverBackgroundColor;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

}

can you please elaborate how to make this done for ie8, with,

```
var childnumber = document.querySelectorAll('.row-strip:nth-child(3)');
```

Comment: if you wanna do it without js or jQuery why did you tag them in your question??!

Comment: ok, sry i wasnot aware of that..now any suggestion please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use querySelectorAll, that works fine in IE8.

```
var childnumber3 = document.querySelectorAll('div:nth-child(3)');
```

Comment: "(I am not supposed to use any js or Jquery)" from OP

Comment: It's pure javascript, you can use it like as fallback for IE8, there are no others simple solutions.

Comment: Oh I agree, there is no other way (unless you control the generation of the HTML). Answer accepted so I guess the quoted sentence wasn't really of any use in the original question :)